# rubyAMF plugin + rails 2.3.4 + raby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, rubyamf

I currently have ruby 1.8.7 running with a Rails 2.3.4 webapp. I'm trying to install the rubyamf plugin from github but I keep getting a 'plugin not found error'. I cloned the repo locally and copied the plugin into the vendor/plugins folder. However, now when i run ruby install.rb, i get this error:  ERROR INSTALLING RUBYAMF: uninitialized constant Rails

How do I install this plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: There are two issues related to your question, which make it very hard for other people to answer it. First, if at all possible immediately stop working on Rails 2.3.4. It is a very, very, very old version. You will get into massive trouble getting it working using modern concepts. Second, the plugin is located here https://github.com/victorcoder/rubyamf_plugin and there are good instructions in the readme. If you cannot understand the instructions, your skill level is too low to complete this task.